# How do I check which video clips I've watched?

Tags: yakuza-0

One of the completion list tasks in Yakuza 0 is to watch 30 different video clips at the erotic video store. Rewatching a clip you've already seen doesn't count.

Is there a way to check what video clips I've already watched?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can view a checklist of the video clips you've watched in the Completion List.

- Pause the game
- Open "Completion List"
- Press the button for "Completion Items". (Y on Xbox controller, shown in bottom right)
- Select "Video Clips"

[image: Checklist of completed Video Clips]